# Set context and fire a method in an xState Action

Tags: reactjs, state-machine, xstate

I have a simple state machine that handles an input form

```
export const chatMachine = Machine({
  id: 'chat',
  initial: 'idle',
  states: {
    idle: {
      on: {
        SET_MESSAGE: { actions: ['handleMessageChange'] },
        COMMENT_SUBMITTED: {
          actions: ['submitComment']
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I would like the `submitComment` action to fire off a function and then reset a field in context like this:

```
submitComment: (ctx, e) => {
            e.payload(ctx.message);
            assign({
              message: ''
            });
          }
```

This doesn't work.

It fires the method I'm passing in but it doesn't make it to the assign bit.

Can I do two thing sin one action or should I be creating two seperate actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be creating two separate actions because those *are* two separate actions.

I'm not sure what `e.payload(ctx.message)` does, but events should be purely data - you should *not* put functions in events.

Also, `assign(...)` is not imperative. It is a pure function that returns an action that looks something like `{ type: 'xstate.assign', ...}`. None of XState's actions are imperative.

Try this:

```js
// ...
COMMENT_SUBMITTED: {
  actions: ['submitComment', 'assignComment']
},

// ...
actions: {
  submitComment: (ctx, e) => { ... },
  assignComment: assign({ message: '' })
}
```

Comment: David, thanks for the helpful answer..what would one in this situation if the assignComment function required some data from the submitComment function? I both need to process some data, and then set it to context.

Comment: You can use the "pure()" action creator to combine both assign calls.

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Hit same problem today, finally get sth like this and that works perfect for me, you cannot use assign() in action but you could directly change the context

```
actions: {
  // ....
  changeToRemove: (context, event, meta) => {
    selection.value.color = 'red'
    context.selectionType = 'remove'
  },
  // ....
}
```

also try this with `setTimeout(() => context.selectionType = 'remove', 2000)` instead of simple assignment, but as expected when you fire sth that already use machine state before 2s then the old value is used so if you want to select sth from API or use some asynchronus actions maybe better solution is to add more states to the machine then after call action send event to the machine to change it state